# Angular 6 call and pass a function from parent to child component

Tags: angular6

I have a button in a child form component and in the from parent component I want to push a function to the child component when the onClose() function is clicked from within the child component. I've tried the method below but the issue is it will work on the first form but not the rest. I would also like to pass other functions as well, including a onSubmit. For me to proceed I will need to figure out what i'm doing wrong here. I've been at this for a few days now any help is appreciated.Thanks

```
child form component, in the template url it contains the button for Onclose()

import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, Input, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl,  ValidatorFn,Form } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-editgraphs',
    templateUrl: './editgraphs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./editgraphs.component.scss']
})
export class EditgraphsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() eGraphtitle: string;
    @Output() close: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    graphDataForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,){}
    ngOnInit(): void {
     this.graphDataForm = this.fb.group({
    sDepartment: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
      });

      }

            onClose() {this.close.emit();}
            onClose2() {this.close.emit();}


parent component

import { Component, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { debug } from 'util';
import { EditgraphsComponent} from './../../../shared/forms/editgraphs/editgraphs.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-payments',
    templateUrl: './payments.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./payments.component.scss']


})
export class PaymentsComponent {
    @ViewChild(EditgraphsComponent) private graphComponent: EditgraphsComponent;
    //graph modal titles
    egraph1Title: string = 'YTD Comparison Data';
constructor() {}

onClose() {

    this.graphComponent.graphDataForm.reset();
    console.log('Resseting and closing YCPC graph.');
}


onClose2() {

    this.graphComponent.graphDataForm.reset();
    console.log('Resseting and closing CMCPG graph.');
}

Parent Template URL


<app-editgraphs #graphComponent  [eGraphtitle]="egraph1Title" (close)="onClose($event)"></app-editgraphs>
    <app-editgraphs #graphComponent  [eGraphtitle]="egraph2Title" (close)="onClose2($event)"></app-editgraphs>
```

Answer (score 30):

**Function parameter approach**

You can pass a function like an @Input like this.

*Parent component*

```
export class PArentComponent {

  fn = function() {
    console.log('hello');
  };
}
```

*Parent template*

```
 <app-child [function]="fn"></app-child>
```

*Child component*

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() function: any;

 ngOnInit() {
       this.function();
 }
}
```

**EventEmitter Approach**

If you need to execute a function that needs to access parent scope variables you could choose an event approach.
Contrary to `@Input` you can use `@Output` that is the angular way to communicate events from child to parent.

*You can define an event in your child component like this:*

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

 @Output() onClose = new EventEmitter();

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 closeModal() {
   // DO SOMETHING

   // emit event onClose
   this.onClose.emit();
   // you can pass also some payload into the event
   this.onClose.emit('all closed');
 }
}
```

*Child template*

```
<button (click)="closeModal()"></button>
```

Then in your Parent Component's template you can catch child component's event like all other events in angular:

```
<app-child (onClose)="execOnClose($event)"></app-child>
```

This piece of code intercepts an `onClose` event with `(onClose)` and executes parent component's `execOnClose()` method.

*So let's look at the parent component*

```
export class ParentComponent {

  execOnClose($event: any) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```

Comment: when I try to call this from the modal form pop up close button. I get Unable to get property 'graphDataForm' of undefined or null referenceTypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'function'. I tried this way before the problem is it calls the functions once the parent component is loaded. that's not the desired affect. I want it to only be called when I press the close button.

Comment: thanks for your help so far but even though the function is passed to the other child form it doesn't reset the form just the first one that called. I'm calling 2 + instances of the child component. I know the simple thing to do is just create multiple child components with the same form data but that will lead to a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: I can't undestand which problem you have with the EventEmitter Approach: passing data to event you can switch into your parent function and achieve whatever you want

Comment: i have a button for <app-form (close)="onClose($event)> on close works fine then i call  from another button <app-form (close)="onClose($event)> the second one the event to reset the form doesn't work but it will pass a string to console. I'm not understanding why it works for the first one and not the second.

Comment: but it executes the desired codes? keep in mind that soma version of angular have form reset function bugged

Comment: Function was executing continuously when i'm passing as an input as, <child [fun]="someFn()"></child>. Can i get any help for this?

Comment: @NandaKishoreAllu you have to remove the parenthesis. with parenthesis you are invoking the function, without parenthesis you are passing it for reference. so you need something like: <child [fun]="someFn"></child>